# How can I display this logo on all the pages except the home page?

Tags: php, html

I have this code PHP:

```
    <?php if (!is_home()){ ?>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-12  col-lg-12  style="">
       <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/LOGOb.png" class="img-responsive center-block" style="min-width:156px;min-height:83px">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is site:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

I want this logo to be displayed on all pages of the home page less and unfortunately tried my code does not work.
Is something wrong?
What should be corrected so that it works?

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work as long as the `is_home()` function works properly.

Comment: if so try all the pages disappears

Comment: If the whole page disappears, you're probably getting an error. Check your PHP error log.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try:

```
!is_front_page()
```

or

```
!is_page('home')
```

use the latter if the slug for your homepage is 'home'

is_home() only works for the posts page, so unless your homepage is the blog, it won't produce results.